# Access restrictions for template arguments

Tags: c++, templates

The section `N4296::14.3/3 [temp.arg]` says:

> **The name** of a template-argument **shall be accessible at the point where**
>   **it is used** as a template-argument. [ Note: If the name of the
>   template-argument is accessible at the point where it is used as a
>   templateargument, **there is no further access restriction in the**
>   **resulting instantiation** where the corresponding template-parameter
>   name is used. —end note ]

All right, let's consider the following example:

```
template <class T> class X{
    static typename T::S ts;
};

class Y {
private:
    class VS{ class S{ }; };
    X<VS> x; //1
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3b67b3fff2e461e9)

Template argument for the template `X` in its instantiation at `//1` is `class VS`. Now, what the Standard said it's this:

> The name of a template-argument **shall be accessible at the point where**
>   **it is used as a template-argument**.

`class VS` is accessible at the point `//1`, therefore the requirement is held. But inspite of the fact that the Standard said that there's no further access restriction, the code is not compiled.

Why the code is not compiled? From what I could say based on the section I provided, it **should be** compiled.

Comment: There are no further restrictions on the use of `T`. That does not mean there are no further restrictions on the use of `T::S`.

Comment: @T.C. Where is it said that the restrctions are on use `T`? __there is no further access restriction in the resulting instantiation__

Comment: "where the corresponding template-parameter name is used"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S is private, try this:

```
template <class T> class X{
   static typename T::S ts;
 };

 class Y {
 private:
   class VS{ public: class S{ }; };
   X<VS> x; //1
 };
```